# What blocks does the fortune enchant work on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) tells us that Fortune applies to a certain set of blocks, but a person who I know and trust tells me that he has seen it work on iron ore, and gold ore blocks, which seems to contradict what I see in the wiki.

Can someone provide a more accurate source, perhaps the decompiled code or something giving a definitive answer as to exactly what the Fortune enchantment applies to?

Comment: Never seen it work on iron ore or gold.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any block which drops an item other than the block itself when mined.

This includes:

- Coal
- Diamond
- Redstone
- Emerald
- Lapis Lazuli
- Nether Quartz
- Melon (capped at 9 melons)
- Clay (Capped at 4, but increases the chance of getting 4)
- Seeds (from tall grass and wheat, but doesn't increase the actual wheat drop itself)
- Nether Wart
- Glowstone (capped at 4 dust, but increases the chance of getting 4)
- Increases the chance of gravel dropping flint
- Increase of dropping saplings and apples from leaves

Fortune works differently for different things. Most notably, at Fortune III you have a 20% chance to get twice as many drops, a 20% chance to get 3 times as many drops and a 20% chance to get 4 times as many drops for Coal, Diamond and Lapis Lazuli.

All others work similarly to Looting on a sword, increasing the maximum limit and therefore increasing the chance that it drops a lot of things, but not explicitly doubling or tripling the dropped amount.

Comment: I was curious if this would work with an axe enchanted with Fortune, and a bookshelf. In case anyone else is curious, bookshelves seem to be the exception to the "any block which drops an item other than the block itself" rule (granted, you did say "mined"); they **always** drop three books.